# MySql trigger with declaration variable not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am getting error "MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @itm_qty decimal(10,2); DECLARE @insert_qty decimal(10,2); SELECT @ins' at line 1".please help me

```
CREATE TRIGGER `updatestockqty` AFTER INSERT ON `billingitemtb` 
FOR EACH ROW 
AS
DECLARE @itm_qty as decimal(10,2); 
DECLARE @insert_qty as decimal(10,2);

SELECT @insert_id=i.bt_itmid from INSERTED i;

select @itm_qty=itemtb.itm_qtyinstock 
from itemtb 
where itemtb.itm_id=@insert_id;

BEGIN 
IF(i.bt_itmqty<@itm_qty)THEN 
UPDATE [db].itemtb
SET itemtb.itm_qtyinstock = itemtb.itm_qtyinstock - NEW.bt_itmqty 
WHERE itemtb.itm_id = NEW.bt_itmid; 
end IF;
END
```

Comment: PLease format your code

Answer (score 0):

As for Starter , DECALRE should be in BEGIN and END

```
CREATE TRIGGER `updatestockqty` AFTER INSERT ON `billingitemtb` 
FOR EACH ROW 
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @itm_qty decimal(10,2); 
DECLARE @insert_qty decimal(10,2);
SET @itm_qty  = select itemtb.itm_qtyinstock 
from itemtb 
where itemtb.itm_id=NEW.bt_itmid -- Change this itemID column to corresponding column in billingitem;
IF(i.bt_itmqty<@itm_qty)THEN 
UPDATE itemtb
SET itemtb.itm_qtyinstock = itemtb.itm_qtyinstock - NEW.bt_itmqty 
WHERE itemtb.itm_id = NEW.bt_itmid; 
end IF;
END
```

From the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement
>   and must be at its start, before any other statements.

Comment: I am still getting error "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS BEGIN  DECLARE @itm_qty as decimal(10,2)' at line 3 0.000 sec'

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE itm_qty decimal; 
DECLARE insert_qty decimal;
declare msg varchar(128);
 select itemtb.itm_qtyinstock INTO itm_qty
  from itemtb 
  where itemtb.itm_id=NEW.bt_itmid;
if new.bt_itmqty < itm_qty THEN 
 UPDATE itemtb
 SET itemtb.itm_qtyinstock = itemtb.itm_qtyinstock - NEW.bt_itmqty 
 WHERE itemtb.itm_id = NEW.bt_itmid; 
ELSE
 set msg = concat('MyTriggerError: Trying to insert a greater qty value in 
           updatestockqty: ');
         signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
end IF;
END
```